# MultitableInput MapReduce with ResultSerialization

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I understand that result serialization is used in case I use a single input table.

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob( tableName, scan, Mapper.class, Text.class, Result.class, job );
```

Any ideas how I can achieve the same while using MultiTableInput (multiple scans as input)?

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob( scans, SummaryMapper.class, Text.class, Result.class, job );
```

I get the following error while running the MR job:

> INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1492475015807_0003_m_000003_2,
>   Status : FAILED Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.init(MapTask.java:988)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:391)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.access$100(MapTask.java:80)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.(MapTask.java:675)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:747)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get through this phase. I explicitly specified the ResultSerialization class in the job config (but must be done before the job instance is created).

```
config.setStrings( "io.serializations", config.get( "io.serializations" ),
                    MutationSerialization.class.getName(), ResultSerialization.class.getName(),
                    KeyValueSerialization.class.getName() );
```

This his how it is specified when the mapper is initialized when using a single input table. 
I will be sure to update this answer if I have any further findings on this so that it may be useful for others who may need it.